# split at entire deliminator but not each component of deliminator

Tags: r, regex

I want to split a string and keep where its being split.

```
str = 'Glenn: $53  Sutter: $44'
strsplit(str, '[0-9]\\s+[A-Z]', perl = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Glenn: $5"  "utter: $44" ## taking out what was matched
strsplit(str, '(?=[0-9]\\s+[A-Z])', perl = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Glenn: $5"     "3"             "  Sutter: $44" ## splitting at each component of the match
```

Is there a way to split it at the entire deliminator? So it returns:

```
# [1] "Glenn: $53"  "Sutter: $44"
```

Comment: Please edit to explain what you mean by "Is there a way to split it at the entire deliminator?", considering that you have not given or even defined a "deliminator". Is the interpretation of your question I gave in my answer correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround to split at one ore more spaces (`\\s+`) before an upper case letter and after a digit

```
strsplit(str, "(?<=[0-9])\\s+(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "Glenn: $53"  "Sutter: $44"
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you wish to split on spaces following strings comprise of a dollar sign followed by one or more digits, provided the spaces are followed by a letter.

By setting `perl = true`, you will use Perl's regex engine, which supports `\K`, which effectively means to discard everything matched so far. You therefore could use the following regex (with the case-indifferent flag set):

```
\$\d+\K\s+(?=[a-z])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbdr7f/3/)

In some cases, as here, `\K` can be used as a substitute for a variable-length lookbehind. Alas, most regex engines, including Perl's, do not support variable-length lookbehinds.